How to Fix AnyHashable Warning with DiffableDataSource in Swift 6.0 and Xcode 16?
After updating my project to Swift 6.0 and Xcode 16, I started encountering warnings when using AnyHashable as an item type in both CollectionView and TableView with DiffableDataSource.
private var dataSource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Section, AnyHashable>!

Warning Message:
Conformance of 'AnyHashable' to 'Sendable' is unavailable; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode.


I’m receiving around 80 warnings across my project because I use AnyHashable in many places. Even though the app works fine, the sheer volume of warnings is annoying and clutters my console.
I came across this Reddit post which seems to mention the same issue. However, I couldn’t find a straightforward solution.
My Question:

What is causing this warning**?
Is there a way to fix or silence these warnings in Swift 6.0?
If a migration away from AnyHashable is required, what would be the best alternative solution for DiffableDataSource?

Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Create own struct AnySendableHashable: Sendable, Hashable

Thanks for the suggestion! However, using a custom struct creates some limitations in my case.
I would only be able to use AnySendableHashable as the item type across all sections. In my current setup, I rely on different AnyHashable item types for different sections, which allows flexibility.
Since structs in Swift don’t support inheritance, I wouldn’t be able to make my existing item types conform to AnySendableHashable. This approach would restrict me to a single item type, which isn’t ideal for my use case.

To be able to use multiple item types in a single data source, I wrap my hashable items with enums using associated values which makes your problem obsolete.
struct Product: Hashable {
   let id = UUID()
}

enum Item: Hashable {
   case grid(Product)
   case list(Product)
}

And when configuring the cell, I set the identifier to my hashable enum to be able to use the associated value.
typealias CellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, Item>

func gridCellRegistration() -> CellRegistration {

   CellRegistration { cell, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
       guard case .grid(let model) = itemIdentifier else { return }
   }

}

func listCellRegistration() -> CellRegistration {

   CellRegistration { cell, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
       guard case .list(let model) = itemIdentifier else { return }
   }

}


I think this is the best approach for my use case. Thank you.

According to docs, UITableViewDiffableDataSource's ItemIdentifierType (the second generic parameter) must conform to Sendable. "Any" types, collectively, can't conform to it, hence the warning.
There's no way to silence this warning, because it relates to Swift 6's compiler-guaranteed data race-safety.
You can use a more specific type that conforms to both Hashable and Sendable, e.g., in the form of a generic parameter:
import UIKit

struct Stuff<Section: Sendable & Hashable, Item: Sendable & Hashable> {
  private var dataSource: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>!
}

